# PHP Task Queue Causing Permissions Errors Between Modules - Google App Engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, cakephp

I have a single application that I deploy on App Engine to two separate modules. The yaml files are the same except for the module name, and they both deploy just fine. When I browse to them directly or make an API call, they both work the same. The problem arises when I try to add a Task from my 'API' module that targets my 'Worker' module. When the task runs, I get this error: `open_basedir restriction in effect`

If I run the exact same code but change the target of the queue from 'Worker' to 'API', it functions properly. How can I get the task queue to worker properly between modules?

Here are my log files.

`0.1.0.2 - - [01/May/2014:14:31:22 -0700] "POST /workers/rankings/retrieve HTTP/1.1" 200 53435 "http://api.nozzle.io/workers/rankings/request" "AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)" "worker.nozzle-app.appspot.com" ms=1643 cpu_ms=887 cpm_usd=0.005972 queue_name=rankings task_name=4250758058839605876 loading_request=1 instance=00c61b117c159c92e66308ef5304fea71208e266 app_engine_release=1.9.4
   W 15:31:21.586 PHP Warning:  include(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/base/data/home/apps/s~nozzle-app/api:1.375535794405971741/Vendor/pear-pear.cakephp.org/CakePHP/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/base/data/home/apps/s~nozzle-app/worker:1.375535782205207071/;/base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk;/php_runtime/versions;/etc) in /base/data/home/apps/s~nozzle-app/worker:1.375535782205207071/Vendor/pear-pear.cakephp.org/CakePHP/Cake/Core/App.php on line 545`

Comment: looks like you are trying to access a file from the module 'worker' that is in the module 'api' which is why you get the error.

Comment: I get that, but I don't have any control over the App Engine filesystem. The two modules are the same code but uploaded separately with two separate yaml files.

Comment: modules are akin to separate applications - so it makes sense that one module cannot see another modules files. however it's not really obvious to me from the question what you're trying to do - do you expect the source files to be shared between the modules?

Comment: I'm not expecting them to share anything. I have a single repo on GitHub that comprises my backend. I want to upload it two separate times to two separate modules. One of those will function as my API endpoint at api.nozzle.io. For my larger processing needs, the other module runs at worker.nozzle.io. I want it to scale differently than api.nozzle.io and I have it set to require an admin login. When the API gets a big chunk of data, I'm creating a task and putting it on a queue targeting the worker. That is the only connection between the two modules and the only time there is an error.

Comment: This seems to have something to do with Cake PHP's automatic class loading: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/5993ac39de1cbf69a3038d4e054f7e48b7ead121/lib/Cake/Core/App.php#L547 The filepath may have been cached in api module and passed to the worker module somehow.

Comment: Derek what's the app id?

Comment: It's nozzle-app. I think that @Mars may be onto something. I think there might be a memcached conflict between the two modules. I've broken the piece that I was testing, so I'm a little ways out from being to test my assumption.